# Pass a widget from one class into another class when instantiation

Tags: python, class, tkinter, widget

I am designing a gui program using python Tkinter. I develop it in class structure, each class contains a frame containing widgets. The problem is, one class need a widget from the other class as an argument, so is the other class. I am confused how to instantiate the class. Here is the code I've tried so far.

```
frame1 = infoframe(lambda : frame2.listbox1)
frame2 = scriptframe(frame1.entry1)
```

every time I call a function in frame1 that need frame2.listbox1 as an argument, the function doesn't recognize frame2.listbox1 as a listbox. I also tried this code:

```
frame1 = infoframe(None)
frame2 = scriptframe(frame1.entry1)
frame1['object'] = frame2.listbox1
```

but still no luck. I make the program in class structure so that the program is well organized, but it seems that it is not as simple as I thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to breakup your code into units such that the dependency graph between the units is acyclic.  This may require that you do something that is ordinarily considered bad style.

Let's consider how Python allows two modules, such as 'a' and 'b', to import each other.  Suppose the main module starts with `import a`. If the import code, after checking for the presence of `sys.modules['a']`, were to execute the 'obvious' `sys.modules['a'] = module('a', code_of_a)`, nothing is added to sys.modules until the module call returns.  When, before the return, a imports b and b tries to import a, `sys.modules['a']` would not exist, and `sys.modules['a'] = module('a', code_of_a)` would be repeated, and so on, until the recursion limit were reached.

To prevent this, import instead breaks module initialization into two phases.  It begins with putting a nearly empty module in sys.modules with something like `sys.modules['a'] = module('a')`.  Then it calls something like `sys.modules['a'].populate(code_of_a)`.  Exposing uninitialized objects is normally considered bad style, but it is essential here.  This is the same idea as what you tried.

Now, when a imports b, module a will have whatever objects have been defined by the previous statements.  When b imports a, it will get the partially initialized module a.  The user just has to arrange that whatever b will need is already initialized before `import b`, so that splitting a into 'a_before' and 'a_after' breaks the dependency cycle.  Putting `import b` somewhere in the middle of the file violates the PEP8 admonition to put imports at the top, but it is necessary in one of the files for mutual import to work.

An alternate solution is to move code from a and b into a new module c that is initialized first.

I hope this gives you some ideas for your situation.